# SVN: How to make a project change its version number when committing to a depending project?

Tags: svn

I have three projects - `project1`, `project2` and `lib`, where `lib` is a static library used by both `project1` and `project2`. I want to place them all in my SVN repository in such a way that every time I commit to `lib` both `project1` and `project2` change their version numbers too. I guess there is no standard or straightforward way to do so in SVN, but maybe some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Preface

Usually it's a duty of build|deploy tools, which can perform any tricks outside ordinary SVN-scope: just use it, because I don't know your choice

Good answer also depends from some conditions: where, when and how you want to have this data:

- in deployed app for internal needs or for visual readable identification
- in the process of development in your WC JFYI only
- permanently stored in repository and usable for ererybody

Some "common process of getting result" can be (dirty) outlined as:

- Create "super-repo" for every complex project (BASE + LIB as external)
- For independent (in terms of "original repository") part of super-repo get mutable during time relevant *id*: revision number can be usable choice (or maybe only for LIB, using tags for BASE)
- With `svnversion` or `subwcrev` or just `svn info` with post-processing on releant trees of super-repo get needed numbers and combine these pieces of data: it can be performed by hand, or server-side hook, or client-side hook in TSVN